# Need to rewrite parameters AND redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to simultaneously do two things with htaccess.

I need to take a URL like:

```
 http://client.example.com/123
```

and rewrite the directory to a param, and simultaneously add another subdomain to the url so it looks like this:

```
 http://client.qa.example.com/?param=123
```

This does the param bit correctly, but I can't figure out how to add the subdir:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /?param=$1 [L]
```

Comment: If you change the domain, it's going to do a Redirect so the URL will change in the browser. Is that also the desired effect you are looking for?

Comment: I don't really care what the browser URL looks like. This is purely for a testing environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the host header using a `RewriteCond` and extract the relevant parts of the name. Use them in the rewrite. Back references to matches in `RewriteCond`s appear as `%n`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+?)\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ http://%1.qa.%2/?param=$1 [R,L]
```

`(.+?)\.(.*)` will do a match on everything up to the first `.` and then everything to the end. So `client` and `example.com` will respectively be in `%1` and `%2`

Comment: This definitely looks right, but I can't seem to get it to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If your .htaccess is in the root of `client.example.com`, it should be a simple redirect. Of course the directory has to be a **fake** directory or this won't redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://client.qa.example.com/?param=$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the directories are all virtual, since they are pointing at a web app.

Comment: @ScoutsOut, that's what I was saying. If they are not real directories it should redirect. Are you saying it's not working?

Comment: No, even client.example.com is a fake directory. Our static website lives at example.com, which is where the htaccess has to go. All directories above that are just through the app.

Comment: Do you have access to your apache config? It's usually not setup by default so to recognize subdomains in the main domain you need to add it to the ServerAlias as `*.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match (check for htaccess syntax):

```
(http://[^.]+\.)([^/]+/)([^/]*)/?$
```

And replace with:

```
$1qa.$2?param=$3
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uI3yI6/1)

Comment: **500 Internal Server Error**

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+?)\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ http://%1.qa.%2/?param=$1 [R,L]
```

Now I just have to figure out how to work in 2 parameters, given that param 2 isn't always going to be present.

Comment: This appears to be an exact clone of my answer! What you should do on Stack Overflow is [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers]) an answer if you've found it has solved your problem